# Does removing logo and general links do any good for better UX in a social network site?

Tags: menu, social-media

I have a social network project in hand. As logo and main menu will be ignored after a while from users, I put the top menu in homepage,contactus,aboutus, and some other general pages.
When user logs in to the SN he will see a top menu which contains stream,edit profile,inbox, friend lists, and so on. The logo is gone.
Does this approach do any good for social network users? Does this offer a better user experience for our users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of the logo is that it is an indicator to users to tell them where they are. It is a recognition thing... so although users may not look at it explicitly it does create a feeling of place. It is also branding so that they will recognise it elsewhere...

I guess this is more important on a website where users can come in from all over the web to your page. You are talking about a web app which is accessed after login (I assume the login page will have the logo on it).

However remember the user still may have multiple applications running and be switching between many different windows. You still need to make it feel distinctive and a logo is an easy and space effective way to do this.

I would suggest keeping it ...

If not try other more subtle ways of making your page distinctive just so that it is distinguishable from other windows....

- reduce the logo's size but add a subtle colour scheme same as the logo
- put the logo as a very light watermark behind the window